# Writing a service just for the purpose of refactoring out persistence logic?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

I have a piece of business logic, that I feel should belong in a domain class. But the logic should end with persisting to the database, and this should obviously not be part of the domain class. So what does this mean;  Will such situation enforce me to put the logic in a Service? Or at least a service referencing the logic methods of the domain class, and then persisting to database.. (?)

Say for example I want to post a transaction into a securities account. Much verification logic is internal to the account fields only, and such it seems this logic should be inside the domain class. But I then need an AccountTransactionService which simply calls this logic of the domain class, receives a true/false, on whether transaction was performed, and then saves the object if changed. It seems it will be many Service classes which only does this type of "forwarding" of methods, and then saving based on the result. But maybe this a very typical nature of services?

Just looking for some advice, as I'm not used to writing service classes, which this well reflects. What other purpose should I consider for the Service class, except just to refactor out the dependency on persistence logic from the domain class?

*Btw, I'm just writing applications for my personal use. So I don't really have to respect all guidelines just for the sake of it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Be agile.

In the typical case it's okay to have such services, so called "Application Services", **but** if you have a lot of logic that lies on the boundary between domain logic and persistence logic that is forcing you to write tons of the almost copy-paste Services that just don't do this. You shouldn't follow any "best practices" if they gives nothing to you.

This is an interesting topic and is very dependent on the particular case, could you please share some code in order to solve concrete problems?